# How can I assing current url to a variable? NodeJS Selenium-webdriver

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I assing current url or current title to a variable

```
let isRedirected = driver.getCurrentUrl()
console.log(isRedirected)
if (isRedirected = 'https://www.xxxx.com//redirect_main.html') {
   await spinner.succeed(chalk.green(`Success: ${chalk.blue(line[0])}`));
} else {console.log('err')}
```

when i tried with this code i got
output:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

and i tried it for currentTitle and i got same output, where is my fault

Comment: Can you change the first line of code to this `let isRedirected =  await driver.getCurrentUrl()` and show us the new output

Comment: it worked. Thanks